# PHP Object of class PHPMailer could not be converted

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have read similar threads but this problem is different. Problem is that 100% same code with same class is working on another page. But it is not working on index page for some odd reason. Here is error I get:

The only difference is that the working file is located in subdirectory on root that is /xyz but the index file is located in root that is / but the action to the form points to file in sub directory that is /xyz/file.php so I don't think that could be a problem.

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class PHPMailer could not be converted to string in `/home4/elliot/public_html/web.com/class.phpmailer.php on line 764`

Here is what PHP Mailer Shows on line 764:

```
$address = trim($address);
```

Here is What working code looks like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->Host = "removed";

$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "removed";

$mail->Password = "removed";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('xx@xx.com', 'John Doe');

$mail->addReplyTo('xx@xx.com', 'John Doe');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($email,$full);

$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Body     =  $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->send();
```

Here is what non working code looks like:

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->Host = "removed";

$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "removed";

$mail->Password = "removed";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('xx@xx.com', 'John Doe');

$mail->addReplyTo('xx@xx.com', 'John Doe');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($email,$full);

$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Body     =  $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->send();
```

Comment: what is on line 764 in  /home4/elliot/public_html/web.com/class.phpmailer.php?

Comment: $address = trim($address);

Comment: And where do you first define $address?

Comment: it is in phpmailer function. It is working on other pages. Just I get this error in the index page

Answer (score 10):

I got it. IT was such a stupid error. I was using $mail variable for both object and also email address.